# Find and replace non matching words in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Here is the example shows how to replace the matching words to uppercase.

```
var str = "Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car.";
    var res = str.replace(/(blue|house|car)/g, function (x) {
        return x.toUpperCase();
      });
```

console.log(res); The out put is

> Mr Blue has a BLUE HOUSE and a BLUE CAR.

But i need the non matching words to uppercase.

> MR BLUE HAS A blue house AND A blue car.

I tried with the below code. But its not working

```
var str = "Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car.";
    var res = str.replace(/!(blue|house|car)/g, function (x) {
        return x.toUpperCase();
      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match the beginning of a word (word boundary, with `\b`), negative lookahead for those three words followed by word boundaries, then match word characters and use your replacer function:

```js
var str = "Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car.";
var res = str.replace(/\b(?!blue\b|house\b|car\b)\w+/g, function(x) {
  return x.toUpperCase();
});
console.log(res);
```

The word boundaries at the end of each of those three words is necessary so that `houses` will be properly matched (and only `house`, as a standalone word, will not be matched).

`!` doesn't mean anything much in a regular expression, it'll just match a literal `!`, which your string doesn't contain anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without regex. first split on each space and than check if it's matching those words or not accordingly change case

```js
var str = "Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car.";
let arr = ['blue','house','car']

var res = str.split(/\b/).reduce( (op,inp) => {
  if( !arr.includes(inp) ){
    op += inp.toUpperCase()
  } else {
    op += inp
  }
  return op
},'')
console.log(res.trim());
```

Comment: `car` is becoming uppercase which is incorrect. Caused by dot after car which you need to handle.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi oh yeah. fixed. thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

You might also split on matching 1+ times a word char `(\w+)` or on a word boundary `\b`. Add the values of the alternation to an array and use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in combination with [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
let str = "Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car.";
let words = ["blue", "house", "car"];
str = str.split(/\b/g).map(x => !words.includes(x) ? x.toUpperCase() : x).join('');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: `car` is becoming uppercase which is incorrect. Caused by dot after car which you need to handle.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Ha, you are right, thank you! I have updated it.